# Is there any difference between "thou wast" and "thou wert"?

Tags: past-tense, archaicisms, early-modern-english

Today I realised for the first time that in the KJV Bible both ***thou wast*** and ***thou wert*** are used, and I was intrigued by the need to have two forms for the same person and number of the *past tense simple* in a language which generally has so few verb inflections.

While looking it up I found the confusing statement:

> As verbs the difference between ***wast*** and ***wert*** is that ***wast*** is (archaic) second-person singular simple past tense indicative of *be* while ***wert*** is (archaic) second-person singular simple past tense of *be* (used with the pronoun "thou"). ([Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/wast/wert))

It's even hilarious: A is different from B, because A = C ***while** (!)* B = C.

Leaving jokes aside, I also found this little reference on a site dedicated to [Shakespeare](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/LanguageCompanion/ThemesAndTopics.aspx?TopicId=40):

> wast -    were -  2nd person singular, past tense -   (RJ II.iv.74)
>
> - ***Thou wast*** never with me [Q wert]
>
> wert -    were -  2nd person singular, past tense -
> (2H4 III.ii.162)
>
> - I would ***thou wert*** a man’s tailor

Does anyone know what the real difference there is between the two? If there isn't any, then why two forms?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### *Wert* is more likely to be subjunctive

In the King James Bible, as well as in some other texts, *wert* appears only in "subjunctive" contexts. Using the online KJV bible search engines at [King James Bible Online](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/search.php?hs=1&q=wert) and the University of Michigan [Bible: King James Version -- Simple Searches](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=simple&format=Long&q1=wert&restrict=All&size=First+100) shows that *wert* always occurs in a construction that licenses the subjunctive mood such as an *if* clause.

However, there is not always a difference: *wert* can also be found as an indicative form. *Be* in its history shows a multitude of forms that aren’t all strictly used for separate functions.

The forms *wast* and *wert* are both exceptions to the general pattern for the occurrence of the second-person singular suffix *-st*, which usually occurred only in the indicative mood of the present tense (for all verbs), and in the indicative mood of the past tense (for weak verbs: verbs with a dental suffix in the past tense). The subjunctive mood is regularly formed without *-st* in the second person singular, just as it is formed without *-s* or *-th* in the third person singular.

Therefore, the expected second-person singular past subjunctive form of *be* is *thou were*; and because *were* is not a weak verb, the Old English second-person singular past indicative did not have *-st* either.

The forms *wast* and *wert* come from irregular addition of the *-(s)t* suffix after the Old English period.

The Oxford English Dictionary says

> As is usual for strong verbs, the 2nd singular past indicative in Old English has the same form as the singular past subjunctive (wǣre , Anglian wēre ; compare Old Saxon 2nd singular past indicative wāri ). By late Middle English, the form has become identical with the plural past indicative and subjunctive as well, except in varieties where there is levelling from the 3rd singular to the 2nd singular past indicative (chiefly in the north and the north midlands). Attempts to mark the form more clearly by attaching distinctive 2nd singular endings (either –st , the ending of the present indicative and the (weak) past indicative of regular verbs, or –t , the ending of preterite-present verbs (e.g. shalt ) and of present indicative art ) result (respectively) in Middle English wast , early modern English werst , and Middle English wert , all of which are continued in English regional varieties. Due to the general obsolescence of the distinctly marked 2nd singular in standard English, no canonical form for the category was established, with both wast and wert surviving in archaic and poetic use.

The form *wert* showed overlap both with indicative *wast* and with subjunctive *were* (and similarly, in the present, the form *beest* showed overlap with both indicative *art* and subjunctive *be*).

Goold Brown's "[Grammar of English Grammars](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Grammar_of_English_Grammars/hmgdAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=wert&pg=PA375&printsec=frontcover)" from 1882, provides the following observations about the usage of *wert,* noting that some grammarians prescribed it as a subjunctive form in opposition to indicative *wast,* but that usage did not necessarily conform to that prescription:

(page 375):

> OBS. 2.--Respecting the verb *wert*, it is not easy to determine whether it is most properly of the indicative mood only, or of the subjunctive mood only, or of both, or of neither. The *regular* and *analogical* form for the indicative, is "Thou *wast*;" and for the subjunctive, "If thou *were*." Brightland exhibits, "I *was* or *were*, Thou *wast* or *wert*, He *was* or *were*," without distinction of mood, for the three persons singular; and, for the plural, *were* only. Dr. Johnson gives us, for the indicative, "Thou wast, *or* wert;" with the remark, "*Wert* is properly of the *conjunctive* mood, and ought not to be used in the indicative."--Johnson's Gram., p. 8. In his conjunctive (or subjunctive) mood, he has, "Thou *beest*," and "Thou *wert*." So Milton wrote, "If thou *beest* he."--*P. Lost,* B. i, l. 84. Likewise Shakspeare: "If thou *beest* Stephano."--*Tempest.* This inflection of *be* is obsolete: all now say, "If thou *be*." But *wert* is still in use, to some extent, *for both moods*; being generally placed by the grammarians in the subjunctive only, but much oftener written for the indicative: as, "Whate'er thou art or *wert*."--Byron's Harold, Canto iv, st. 115. "O thou that *wert* so happy!"--*Ib.*, st. 109. "Vainly *wert* thou wed."--*Ib.,* st. 169.
>
> OBS. 3.--Dr. Lowth gave to this verb, BE, that form of the subjunctive mood, which it now has in most of our grammars; appending to it the following examples and questions: "'Before the sun, Before the Heavens, thou *wert.*'--*Milton.* 'Remember what thou *wert*.'--*Dryden.* 'I knew thou *wert* not slow to hear.'--*Addison.* 'Thou who of old *wert* sent to Israel's court.'--*Prior.* 'All this thou *wert*.'--*Pope.* 'Thou, Stella, *wert* no longer young.'--*Swift.* Shall we, in deference to these great authorities," asks the Doctor, "allow *wert* to be the same with *wast*, and common to the indicative and [the] subjunctive mood? or rather abide by the practice of our best ancient writers; the propriety of the language, which requires, as far as may be, distinct forms, for different moods; and the analogy of formation in each mood; I *was*, thou *wast*; I *were*, thou *wert?* all which conspire to make *wert* peculiar to the subjunctive mood."--*Lowth's Gram.,* p. 37; *Churchill's,* p. 251. I have before shown, that several of the "best ancient writers" *did not inflect* the verb *were*, but wrote "*thou were;*" and, surely, "the analogy of formation," requires that the subjunctive *be not inflected.* Hence "the propriety which requires distinct forms," requires not *wert*, in either mood. Why then should we make this contraction of the old indicative form *werest,* a *solitary exception,* by fixing it in the subjunctive only, and that in opposition to the best authorities that ever used it? It is worthier to take rank with its kindred *beest,* and be called an *archaism.*
>
> OBS. 4.--The chief characteristical difference between the indicative and the subjunctive mood, is, that in the latter the verb is *not inflected at all,* in the different persons: IND. "Thou *magnifiest* his work." SUBJ. "Remember that thou *magnify* his work."--*Job,* xxxvi, 24. IND. "He *cuts* off, *shuts* up, and *gathers* together." SUBJ. "If he *cut* off, and *shut* up, or *gather* together, then who can hinder him?"--Job, xl, 10. There is also a difference of meaning. The Indicative, "If he *was*," admits the *fact*; the Subjunctive, "If he *were*," supposes that he was not. These moods may therefore be distinguished by the sense, even when their forms are alike: as, "Though *it thundered*, it did not rain."--"Though *it thundered*, he would not hear it." The indicative assumption here is, "Though it *did thunder*," or, "Though there *was thunder;*" the subjunctive, "Though it *should thunder,*" or, "Though there *were* thunder." These senses are clearly different. Writers however are continually confounding these moods; some in one way, some in an other. [...]

Comment: Because *thou wast* and later *thou wert* both saw use as past indicative, while *thou were* and later *thou wert* both saw use for past subjunctive, we can be sure in this particular pair of cases exactly which of those two moods that Shakespeare happened to be using here. That makes it much easier: [...]

Comment: When Romeo uses *wast* twice in *Thou **wast** never with me for anything when thou **wast** not there for the goose*, we can be certain that that was a past indicative use because (1) *wast* was never used for subjunctive, and (2) this is in a clausal context that always took indicative. But when Falstaff says *I would thou **wert** a man's tailor, that thou mightst mend him and make him fit to go*, he is using *wert* in a clause governed by *would* (modern *wish*) and so we can be sure that he would have used a past subjunctive there.

Comment: Citing Lowth is a giveaway. It was almost certainly a dialectal variant (there were hundreds) that got caught up and used because it "sounded right" to some folks, while other words sounded right to others. The result was the mix of dialects and spelings we laughingly call "Middle English". There never was a standard, certainly never for spelling, and that's all we've got because ME was pre-printing.

Comment: I'm glad you dug in and improved this answer. I learned a lot here.